# Prevent anaconda from adding `(base)` to prompt when no virtual-env is activated (i.e. virtual-env = anaconda base)

Tags: anaconda, virtualenv, command-prompt

I have installed Anaconda (on macOS).

Now every terminal prompt looks like this:

```
(base)
pi@πPro ~/google-drive/vault
>
```

This is really annoying. How do I get rid of that `(base)`?

*RESEARCH:*

Anaconda has made the following one-line change to a function *I wrote* in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
function cd() {  # also activate any venv
  builtin cd "$@"

  if [ -d env ] ; then
    if [ ! -z $VIRTUAL_ENV ] ; then
      deactivate
    fi
# . ./env/bin/activate  # commented out by conda initialize
  fi
}
```

Later in the same file it has inserted a block:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/usr/local/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/usr/local/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/usr/local/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour can be disabled with `conda config --set auto_activate_base false`.

Refer to this issue for details: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8211